# unable to connect to mySQL Db

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie to PHP and to the net world, and trying to connect to a mySQL Db using this PHP code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World \n";

$mysql_host = "MySQL Host"; // this is what specified to use in mySQL management page at my host
$mysql_database = "mysql_database";
$mysql_user = "mysql_user";
$mysql_password = "mysql_password";

echo $mysql_host;

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use '.$mysql_database.' : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

please, what can be wrong with this code? I couldn't find any syntax error and still - I am not able to connect to the Db

can it be and the problem is related to the host only?

Comment: Your MySQL database's hostname is most certainly not `MySQL Host`. More likely it is `localhost` on a shared hosting service.

Comment: Also you are using the 'mysql' extension. You shouldn't. Use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements to avoid SQL injection holes.

Comment: What error message do you get when calling `mysqlerror();`

Comment: I second the suggestion to use mysqli or another MySQL interface.  Also consult a tutorial, such as this one on mysqli: http://www.willfitch.com/mysqli-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

The following variables should contain values that are respectively:

- `$mysql_host` - IP or host name of the server with your database,
- `$mysql_database` - name of the database,
- `$mysql_user` - name of the database user,
- `$mysql_password` - password for specific user to the specific database,

Make sure all of them are correct and then the problem should be resolved. If it is not, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually typing `MySQL Host` in your code, then you're not providing a valid hostname. You should try with `localhost` instead.

Otherwise, you current host must have provided you with the needed information.

You should also tell us what error your script gives you, when it dies. That enables us to give a qualified answer instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

as @Michael says,

```
$mysql_host = "MySQL Host";
```

is definitely wrong, that field must have a either a valid host/socketname or localhost..

Answer (score 0):

These guys are spot on. Also, the password is usually blank on a localhost program.

But, this is just something I noticed:

Your $conn variable is missing an 'n' in your 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing connection in $conn but in if condition you are checking with ($con).
(There might be other errors. But I can see this error)